# Number of decimal places returned by dividing integers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

--in sql server 2005.

```
SELECT 5/13;   ----> 0  
SELECT Cast(5/13 AS real); --> 0  
SELECT 5.00/13.00; --> 0.3846153 
SELECT cast(5/13 as decimal(10, 2));        --> 0.00 
SELECT cast(5 as decimal)/cast(13 as Decimal); --> 0.3846153846153846153
```

Is there a global setting for number of decimal places returned by dividing integers? All I need is to have the result as .38

Comment: Try Select cast(5/(13+0.0) as decimal(10,2))

Comment: First, read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql  Also, I strongly recommend you read online about the differences between `REAL` *(a floating point type)* and `DECIMAL` *(a fixed point type)*.

Comment: When deviding integers the result is always an integrer as well...

Answer (score 0):

There is no global setting.  (That is the question you are asking.)

When you divide two integers, the result is an integer.  You simply want to express the value to two decimal places.  John Capelletti has the right answer in a comment.  Convert the values to non-integers and then convert back to the format you want.  I normally do this by multiplying by 1.0:

```
select cast((5 * 1.0 / 13) as decimal(10, 2)
```

There are quite arcane rules for the number of decimal places produced when you do arithmetic on decimal values.